# Sicstus prolog: labeling a list in a list

Tags: prolog, clpfd

it's quite a long time since I'm dealing with a problem of labeling in Sicstus prolog. I want to create an array of length 7, where each item is again an array of 4 integers. I tried following code, but it doesn't work and gives an instantiation error.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

schedule(Ss) :-    
    length(Ss, 7),
    Ss = [[A, B, C, D]|T],
    solve_days(Ss),
    labeling([], Ss).

solve_days([]).
solve_days([[A, B, C, D]|T]):-
    A in 1..3,
    B in 4..7,
    C in 7..9,
    D in 6..10,
   solve_days(T).
```

Can anyone give me an advice how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: From http://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Membership-Constraints.html#Membership-Constraints

domain/3 is for a list of variables. For single variables "in" should be used. Don't forget to set T a domain as well.

Comment: Thanks hakank. I made some changes. Sicstus prolog is saying Type error in argument 2 of user:labeling/2
! expected an integer, but found [_128,_130,_132,_134]
! goal:  labeling(user:[],[[_128,_130,_132,_134],[_13

Comment: Renamed tite from "array" to "list", for reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The argument for labeling must be a plain list. One way to fix this is use use append/3 to flatten A..D and T, e.g. `append([A,B,C,D],T,Vars)`.

Answer (score 1):

An approach often seen to solve this kind of annoyance, is to use the predicate `term_variables/2` before calling labeling.

The predcate `term_variables/2` is an ISO core predicate since Corr.2 and determines the list of variables in a term.

In the present case one would replace

```
labeling([], Ss)
```

by

```
term_variables(Ss, Vars), labeling([], Vars)
```